# Instagram browser not showing mobile website correctly

Tags: javascript, mobile, browser, instagram

I am struggling with the instagram browser. I made a wordpress website, which is working fine on any browser except instagram. The problem here is that the javascript code is not loading.

Is there some kind of fix to ensure instagram to load all my scripts? Or else is there way to always open the link in the instagram profile in an external browser instead?

Any help is appreciated.

I tried to defer my script but that did not fix it.

Comment: In-app browsers are like that by design. There are [some ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68258427/how-open-default-browser-from-instagram-in-app-browser-page-link) to [go around it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76888215/open-link-in-system-browser-instead-of-in-app-browser), but [your mileage may vary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53217071/instagram-links-open-in-app-browser-instead-of-external-native-browser). There is also [this](https://am-i-inapp-browser.vercel.app/).